# MySql Loan table, for each borrower find the root lender

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data, mysql-5.7, hierarchical

I have a Mysql table as shown below:

```
BORROWER      Lender

1             2
2             3
3             4
4             NULL
5             NULL
6             7
7             5
```

I want to get the root lender for every borrower. You can think of root lender as source of money. So if a person '1' borrows from person '2' and person '2' borrows from person '3' then for person '1' the source of lending(i.e. root lender) is person '3'.
The expected output shown below should help in understanding the problem better:

```
BORROWER      ROOT_LENDER

1             4
2             4
3             4
4             4
5             5
6             5
7             5
```

As you can see, a borrower who does not borrow from anybody(NULL in the LENDER column) is considered to borrow from himself in the output.

In my case this borrower-lender hierarchy can be very large( more than 200k), I guess recursion might not be a good approach, but any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, consider the following recursive query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select borrower original_borrower, borrower, lender, 0 lvl from mytable
    union all
    select c.original_borrower, t.borrower, t.lender, lvl + 1 
    from mytable t
    inner join cte c on t.borrower = c.lender
)
select original_borrower borrower, lender
from cte c
where lvl = (
    select max(lvl) - 1 from cte c1 where c1.original_borrower = c.original_borrower
)
order by original_borrower
```

The recursive query starts from all records available in the table and climbs the hierarchy tree, while keeping track of the original `borrower` and of the level in the tree. Then, the outer query filters on the last record in each subtree.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=666299867a710cc5cae0a42d8ad476a3)**:

```
borrower | lender
-------: | -----:
       1 |      4
       2 |      4
       3 |      4
       6 |      5
       7 |      5
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some options:

Starting from MySQL 8 you can execute recursive CTE queries. For instance

```
with recursive x (borrower, root_lender) as (
    select borrower, borrower root_lender from rels where lender is null
    union all
    select r.borrower, x.root_lender from rels r inner join x on r.lender = x.borrower
)
select * from x order by borrower;
```

But you told that you have a lot of relations.

Another way is to store in another tree representation.

1. Add `root_lender` to each row and fulfill it on each insert;
2. Store tree as a materialized path. You have to add a new one column that stores a path to the current node.

Comment: Can you explain the "Another way" in more detail? Specially the 2nd point.

Comment: yeap. Add an additional column in which the path will be stored. For instance:

`borrower | lender | path`
`1 | NULL | /1`
`2 | 1 | /1/2`
`3 | 2 | /1/2/3`
`4 | 1 | /1/4`


you see that using one query you could fetch all borrowers for each lender, not only root I mean.